# How can I manipulate storage devices outside of Docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers, volume, disk

I'd like to spin up an Ubuntu image with certain tools like testdisk for disk recovery.  How can I manage all detected volumes on the host machine with testdisk inside a Docker container?

Comment: Docker doesn't simulate hardware devices.  You probably need a virtual machine for this.  If you're trying to recover the host system, run the tools directly on the host.

Comment: My thought was that named pipes or bind mounts could be used.  Similar to running dd on Windows, could you map \\.\PhysicalDisk0 as /dev/sd# via a mount bind to Docker?  Would it be just a mount point or raw access to the disk?

Comment: Found out how to do it with Linux/Unix during the docker run phase...not sure about Windows. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/docker-cookbook/9781783984862/ch02s13.html

Answer (score 0):

The O'reilly info worked for Windows with supposed limitations (inability to repartition). I'm assuming if you use disk management to see the disk number (0,1,2,etc) it will correspond to the sd# you have to reference.  Supposedly with Windows Server Editions, you can use the device flag and specify a device class GUID to share inside Docker.  But like previously mentioned, it isn't raw access but rather a shared device.